# is FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize called on every activity created or only on the mainActivity

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

How many times in an application do i need to call
`FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());`
there another question having this issue but it doesn't answer completely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially, the this function was to be called in the application class once. 
However, now it is deprecated.

From the documentation about upgrading SDK:

> The Facebook SDK is now auto initialized on Application start. If you
>   are using the Facebook SDK in the main process and don't need a
>   callback on SDK initialization completion you can now remove calls to
>   FacebookSDK.sdkInitialize. If you do need a callback, you should
>   manually invoke the callback in your code.

Refer to: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/upgrading-4x

Comment: so i should do against the steps in the facebook site and just remove both?

Comment: actually if you go to the quick start and upgrade to the latest, you actually do not need it.

Comment: great that does it